# Not able to add, update, delete rows in material table react using class based component. Previously it was working with functional component

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am not able to add, update or delete and row in material-table. If i initialize data into state then it just display it but not able to edit or delete it, neither i can add data into table. The entered data into the table is reflecting in state as well but when component re-renders after setState it not displayed in table.
The code given on official website is also behaving the same way as mine.
link to example on official site: **https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable** 
I have created a codesandbox for referal: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-pqq3t?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fdemo.js&theme=dark 
 One thing which i am not able to get is that when i initialize data to state one new property is added to the data i.e tableData. But when I add data in state from table then that property is not set to those objects[image] 
This is my code: `

```
state = {
    openDialog: false,
    nameOfCustomer: "",
    date: new Date(),
    items: [{ item: 'Mehmet', cost: 10, quantity: 7, total: null }],
    tax: 0,
    total: 0,
    roundoff: 0,
    columns: [
        { title: 'Item', field: 'item', },
        { title: 'Quantity', field: 'quantity', type: 'numeric', },
        { title: 'Cost/Item', field: 'cost', type: 'numeric', },
        { title: 'Total', field: 'total', type: 'numeric', editable: 'never' },
    ],
}

// componentDidUpdate(){
//     // console.log(this.props.invoices)
// }

handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ openDialog: false })
}

feedDataIntoStore = () => {
    const { nameOfCustomer, date, items } = this.state;
    const storeData = { nameOfCustomer, date, items };
    if (!nameOfCustomer || items.length === 0 || !date) this.setState({ openDialog: true });
    // console.log(storeData);
    this.props.dispatch(createInvoice(storeData));
}

handleItemListData = (data) => {
    this.setState({ items: data.items, total: data.total, tax: data.tax, roundoff: data.roundoff })
}

handleNameChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ nameOfCustomer: e.target.value })
}

handleDateChange = newDate => {
    this.setState({
        date: newDate
    })
};
render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (<React.Fragment>
        <Container>
            <Paper className={classes.root}>

                <Typography variant="h5" component="h3">
                    Create Invoice
                </Typography>

                <Divider style={{ marginTop: 15, marginBottom: 15 }} />

                <TextField
                    id="standard-full-width"
                    label="Name"
                    style={{ margin: 8 }}
                    placeholder="Name of Customer"
                    margin="normal"
                    fullWidth
                    value={this.state.nameOfCustomer}
                    onChange={this.handleNameChange}
                    InputLabelProps={{
                        shrink: true,
                    }}
                />

                <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                    <KeyboardDatePicker
                        style={{ margin: 8, marginBottom: 20 }}
                        margin="normal"
                        id="date-picker-dialog"
                        label="Date picker dialog"
                        format="dd/MM/yyyy"
                        value={this.state.date}
                        onChange={this.handleDateChange}
                        KeyboardButtonProps={{
                            'aria-label': 'change date',
                        }}
                />
                </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
                {console.log(this.state.items)}
                <MaterialTable
                    title="Items"
                    enableRowDelete={true}
                    enableRowAdd={true}
                    columns={this.state.columns}
                    data={this.state.items}
                    editable={{
                        onRowAdd: newData =>
                            new Promise(resolve => {
                                setTimeout(() => {
                                    resolve();
                                    const newItems = this.state.items;
                                    if (!newData.cost || !newData.quantity) {
                                        this.setState({dialogOpen: true });
                                        // handleDateChange({ items: state.items, total, tax, roundoff });
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        let newtotal = 0, newtax = 0, newroundoff = 0;
                                        newData.total = parseFloat((newData.cost * newData.quantity).toFixed(2));
                                        newItems.push(newData);
                                        newItems.forEach((item) => { newtotal = newtotal + parseFloat(item.total, 10) });
                                        newtotal.toFixed(2);
                                        newtax = parseFloat(((newtotal / 100) * 28).toFixed(2));
                                        newroundoff = parseFloat((Math.round(newtotal + newtax) - (newtotal + newtax)).toFixed(2));
                                        newtotal = parseInt(Math.round(newtotal + newtax));
                                        this.setState({ items: newItems, tax: newtax, roundoff: newroundoff, total: newtotal });
                                    }
                                }, 500);
                            }),
                        onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
                            new Promise(resolve => {
                                setTimeout(() => {
                                    resolve();
                                    if (oldData) {
                                        const newItems = this.state.items;
                                        if(!newData.cost || !newData.quantity) 
                                        this.setState({dialogOpen: true})
                                        else{    
                                            let newtotal = 0, newtax = 0, newroundoff = 0;
                                            newData.total = parseFloat((newData.cost * newData.quantity).toFixed(2));
                                            newItems[newItems.indexOf(oldData)] = newData;
                                            newItems.forEach((item) => { newtotal = newtotal + parseFloat(item.total, 10) });
                                            newtotal.toFixed(2);
                                            newtax = parseFloat(((newtotal / 100) * 28).toFixed(2));
                                            newroundoff = parseFloat((Math.round(newtotal + newtax) - (newtotal + newtax)).toFixed(2));
                                            newtotal = parseInt(Math.round(newtotal + newtax));
                                            this.setState({ items: newItems, tax: newtax, roundoff: newroundoff, total: newtotal });
                                        }
                                    }
                                }, 500);
                            }),
                            onRowDelete: oldData =>
                            new Promise(resolve => {
                                setTimeout(() => {
                                    resolve();
                                        const newItems = this.state.items;
                                        let newtotal = 0, newtax = 0, newroundoff = 0;
                                        newItems.splice(newItems.indexOf(oldData), 1);
                                        newItems.forEach((item) => { newtotal = newtotal + parseFloat(item.total, 10) });
                                        newtotal.toFixed(2);
                                        newtax = parseFloat(((newtotal / 100) * 28).toFixed(2));
                                        newroundoff = parseFloat((Math.round(newtotal + newtax) - (newtotal + newtax)).toFixed(2));
                                        newtotal = parseInt(Math.round(newtotal + newtax));
                                        this.setState({ items: newItems, tax: newtax, roundoff: newroundoff, total: newtotal });
                                }, 500);
                            }),
                    }}
                    options={{
                        rowStyle: {
                            backgroundColor: '#EEE',
                        },
                        actionsColumnIndex: 3,
                        search: false,
                        minBodyHeight: 300,
                        loadingType: "linear",
                    }}
                    components={{
                        Cell: props => (
                            <MTableCell {...props} className={classes.noBorder} />
                        ),
                        EditField: props => (
                            <MTableEditField {...props} className={classes.customWidth} />
                        ),
                        Pagination: props => (
                            <TableCell colSpan={3} className={classes.footerFix}>
                                <Box component="span" m={1} className={classes.flex}>
                                    <Typography variant="h6" component="span" align={"center"}>Tax Amount: </Typography>
                                    <Typography variant="h6" component="span" align={"center"}>{this.state.tax}</Typography>
                                </Box>
                                <Divider variant="middle" />
                                <Box component="span" m={1} className={classes.flex}>
                                    <Typography variant="h5" component="span" align={"center"}>Total Amount: </Typography>
                                    <span style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", height: "3em", alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
                                        <Typography variant="button" component="span" align={"center"}><span>Round off.</span> <span>{this.state.roundoff}</span></Typography>
                                        <Typography variant="h5" component="span" align={"center"}>{this.state.total}</Typography>
                                    </span>
                                </Box>
                            </TableCell>
                        ),
                    }}
                />

                <DisableFieldEditable />
                <AlertDialog text = {"Please Enter All Data....."} title = {"Invalid Input"} open = {this.state.openDialog} handleClose = {this.handleClose}/>

                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className={classes.button} onClick={this.feedDataIntoStore}>
                    Create Invoice
                </Button>
            </Paper>
        </Container>
                <AlertDialog text={"You Need To Provide All The Data To Create Invoice, Fields Can't Be Kept Empty"} title={"Can't Create Invoice"} open={this.state.openDialog} handleClose={this.handleClose} />
    </React.Fragment>);
}
```

`

Answer (score 3):

You are mutating the data object in the state instead of updating it immutable.

Because of this, react will skip the rerender and the new data will not be passed to the table. If the references of all objects within the state are the same than
before, react will bail out early. By creating a new object with `data: [...data, newData]`, you change the reference of the data object and react will correctly rerender.

Change it to this and it works:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
              data: [...prevState.data, newData]
            }), resolve);
          }, 1000);
        })
```

This is just an example code for `onRowAdd` and would need to be changed for `onRowUpdate` and `onRowDelete`. But this is the general idea.

This also applies to the useState hook, which would something line this:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
...

setData(prevData => [...prevData, newData])
```

Comment: This answer helped me with an issue I was having.  I was trying to push to an array, but by returning a new array I was able to see the page update.

Comment: That made my day too! Thanks!

Comment: @Domino987 This didnt work with react hook, do u know y?

Comment: It should. But you would need to show some code.

Comment: @Domino987 https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-cori-1s9oe?file=/src/App.js the code

Comment: issue was elsewhere... ur code works thanks man XD

Comment: haha ok, great xD

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Domino987 is almost right. The only problem is that while updating a row, this adds a new row. So there is my solution:

```
                         onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
                         new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                             setTimeout(() => {
                               let clone = [];
                               Object.assign(clone, this.state.data);
                               console.log("clone1:", clone);
                               const index = this.state.data.indexOf(oldData);
                               clone[index] = newData;
                               this.setState({ data:clone }, () => {
                                 resolve();
                               });
                             }, 1000);
                           }),
```

Warning: Object.assign might not be the suitable clone method depending on your data structure.

Comment: Thanks, this made my day!